# IdentityServer4 Role Based Authorization on multiple roles

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, identityserver4

I want to implement multiple role-based authorizations with IdentityServer4 hybrid, everything is fine but when I want to use like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,SalaryUser")]
```

it doesn't allow me and give access denied.

In my scenario, users have multiple roles and if a role is valid the controller should give me access, for example in the above code the controller should give access to these users:
the users have the SalaryUser role, the users with admin roles, the users have both Admin, SalaryUser roles.

here is configuration:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                    {
                        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                        options.Authority = authority;
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        options.ClientId = clientId;
                        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                        options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
                        options.SaveTokens = true;
                        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;





                        options.ClaimActions.MapCustomJson("role", jobj =>
                        {
                            IEnumerable<string> values = jobj["http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"].Values<string>();
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            foreach (string val in values)
                            {
                                sb.Append(val + ",");
                            }
                            return sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
                        });

                        options.Scope.Add("api1");
                        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                       // options.Scope.Add("roles");

                        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                        {

                            OnUserInformationReceived = async UserInformationReceivedContext =>
                            {
                                // UserInformationReceivedContext.User.Remove("address");

                                if (UserInformationReceivedContext.User.TryGetValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", out JToken role))
                                {
                                    var claims = new List<Claim>();
                                    if (role.Type != JTokenType.Array)
                                    {
                                        claims.Add(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", (string)role));
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        foreach (var r in role)
                                            claims.Add(new Claim("role", (string)r));
                                    }
                                    var id = UserInformationReceivedContext.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                                    id.AddClaims(claims);
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        options.ClaimActions.MapAll();
                    });
```

Comment: The article [Missing Claims in the ASP.NET Core 2 OpenID Connect Handler?](https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/) will probably solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually map claims with `MapCustomJson` or in your `OnUserInformationReceived` .

If the claim in jwt token is `role` not `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/role` , you can set client app's role validation claim :

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    RoleClaimType = "role"
};
```

Another way is when adding role claim to your issued token on identity server application , use `ClaimTypes.Role` :

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to map the JWT claim type to the claim type that Identity uses.

The issue at hand is that the identity system for ASP.NET Core relies on
the `ClaimTypes.Role` constant
(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/role) to
determine the roles of the user. However, the name of the claim that
corresponds to the role on an OpenID JWT token is simply `role`. Any
time you need to merge OIDC identity and ASP.NET identity, you have to translate
claims like this.

I rewrote your code a little bit because you can work with the claims identity without using the JTokenType. Although I didn't have time to test this thoroughly so if it doesn't then stick to your code but replace "role" with ClaimTypes.Role when you add claims to the identity.

```cs
            OpenIdConnectEvents CreateOpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                return new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                {
                    OnTicketReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                        if (identity != null)
                        {
                            if (identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "role"))
                            {
                                foreach (var role in identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "role"))
                                {
                                    if (!context.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && c.Value == role.Value))
                                    {
                                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Value));
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
            }
```

Use like this:

```cs
options.Events = new CreateOpenIdConnectEvents()
```